# ffmpeg FLV to FLV conversion fails

Tags: php, ffmpeg, clipbucket

I am using ClipBucket. I have set up ffmpeg, and I can convert AVI, WMV files to FLV video files without any problem, but now I am trying to convert a FLV video file to FLV video file with different video quality.

However, there is an error in the conversion. Can someone help me please?

Logs:

```
Preparing file...
Unknown file details - Unable to get video details using FFMPEG 

Converting Video
Conversion Command : /usr/local/bin/ffmpeg -i /home/myspace86/myspace86.com/files/conversion_queue/136667418894906.flv -f flv -vcodec libx264 -r 30 -vf 'movie=/home/myspace86/public_html/player_logo.png [watermark]; [in][watermark] overlay=main_w-overlay_w-10:main_h-overlay_h-10 [out]' -ab 320000 /home/myspace86/myspace86.com/files/videos/136667418894906.flv 2> /home/myspace86/myspace86.com/files/temp/136667424191b8e.tmp
```

Conversion Details

```
ffmpeg version N-52385-g6d7ec4f Copyright (c) 2000-2013 the FFmpeg developers
built on Apr 22 2013 16:08:27 with gcc 4.1.2 (GCC) 20080704 (Red Hat 4.1.2-54)
configuration: --prefix=/usr/local --enable-shared --enable-gpl --enable-version3 --enable-nonfree --enable-postproc --enable-libfaac --enable-libmp3lame --enable-libopencore-amrnb --enable-libopencore-amrwb --enable-libvpx --enable-libx264 --enable-libxvid
libavutil 52. 27.100 / 52. 27.100
libavcodec 55. 5.100 / 55. 5.100
libavformat 55. 3.100 / 55. 3.100
libavdevice 55. 0.100 / 55. 0.100
libavfilter 3. 60.101 / 3. 60.101
libswscale 2. 2.100 / 2. 2.100
libswresample 0. 17.102 / 0. 17.102
libpostproc 52. 3.100 / 52. 3.100
Input #0, flv, from '/home/myspace86/myspace86.com/files/conversion_queue/136667418894906.flv':
Metadata:
metadatacreator : Yet Another Metadata Injector for FLV - Version 1.4
hasKeyframes : true
hasVideo : true
hasAudio : true
hasMetadata : true
canSeekToEnd : false
datasize : 40992128
videosize : 37546219
audiosize : 3247153
lasttimestamp : 728
lastkeyframetimestamp: 727
lastkeyframelocation: 40978250
Duration: 00:12:08.16, start: 0.000000, bitrate: 450 kb/s
Stream #0:0: Video: vp6f, yuv420p, 648x459, 409 kb/s, 29.97 tbr, 1k tbn, 1k tbc
Stream #0:1: Audio: mp3, 22050 Hz, mono, s16p, 32 kb/s
[libx264 @ 0x146d900] height not divisible by 2 (648x459)
Output #0, flv, to '/home/myspace86/myspace86.com/files/videos/136667418894906.flv':
Metadata:
metadatacreator : Yet Another Metadata Injector for FLV - Version 1.4
hasKeyframes : true
hasVideo : true
hasAudio : true
hasMetadata : true
canSeekToEnd : false
datasize : 40992128
videosize : 37546219
audiosize : 3247153
lasttimestamp : 728
lastkeyframetimestamp: 727
lastkeyframelocation: 40978250
Stream #0:0: Video: h264, yuv420p, 648x459, q=-1--1, 90k tbn, 30 tbc
Stream #0:1: Audio: none, 22050 Hz, mono, s16p
Stream mapping:
Stream #0:0 -> #0:0 (vp6f -> libx264)
Stream #0:1 -> #0:1 (mp3 -> libmp3lame)
Error while opening encoder for output stream #0:0 - maybe incorrect parameters such as bit_rate, rate, width or height


Unknown file details - Unable to get output video details using FFMPEG 


Time Took : 0.3056 seconds

conversion_status : completed
```

Answer (score 1):

```
[libx264 @ 0x146d900] height not divisible by 2 (648x459)
```

That's your error. In general, when working with arbitrary input, you might want to include a scaler that forces output divisible by 2, e.g. the following, where the height is fixed to 460:

```
scale=trunc(oh*a*2)/2:460
```

Or you parse your input file before and see if there's any rescaling needed. See also: [ffmpeg/avconv force scaled output to be divisible by 2](https://superuser.com/questions/571141/ffmpeg-avconv-force-scaled-output-to-be-divisible-by-2/571142#571142)